# Filter a List based on a parameter in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to filter a list of Subjects inside a list of student based on a particular subject i.e. `"maths"` in my case.

Below is the code which defines Student and Subject class.

```
 case class Student(
    name:String,
    age:Int,
    subjects:List[Subject]
  )

  case class Subject(name:String)

  val sub1=Subject("maths")
  val sub2=Subject("science")
  val sub3=Subject("english")
  val s1=Student("abc",20,List(sub1,sub2))
  val s2=Student("def",20,List(sub3,sub1))

  val sList=List(s1,s2)
```

**Expected Output is**

list of students`(s1,s2)` with filtered subjects as explained below

`s1 contains Student("abc",20,List(sub1))` and `s2 contains Student("def",20,List(sub1))` i.e `sub2 and sub3` is filtered out.

I tried below but it didnot worked

```
 val filtered=sList.map(x=>x.subjects.filter(_.name=="maths"))
```

Comment: " it didnot worked"   I know someone's answered  your question already but please don't put "it did not work" without saying in what way it didn't work (and ideally, say what it did do instead and how it differed from what you expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did doesn't work because you turn the list of students into a list of (list of) subjects.

What I do below is keeping each student, but modify their list of subjects

```
sList.map(student => student.copy(subjects = student.subjects.filter(_.name=="maths")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are students in the list who didn't sign up for the subject in question then I assume you wouldn't want that student in the result list.

```
val s3=Student("xyz",20,List(sub2,sub3))

val sList=List(s1,s2,s3)
sList.flatMap{s =>
  if (s.subjects.contains(sub1))         // if sub1 is in the subjects list
    Some(s.copy(subjects = List(sub1)))  // drop all others from the list
  else 
    None  // no sub1 in subjects list, skip this student
}
```